# gnu `uniq -c`: display counts graphically as bars

Tags: command-line, shell, gnu, uniq

With `sort $file | uniq -c`, it's possible to sum up files/input and show the number occurences like that:

```
 13     foo
  1     bar
```

To get a better grasp of this data, I'd like to see them graphically like git does when showing changes (`++++++++--`):

```
------------ foo
-            bar
------       baz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little search gave me [that](http://www.smallmeans.com/notes/shell-history/), which works beautifully, just adapt the name of your input file:

```
uniq -c YOURFILE|awk '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -rn|head -20|awk '!max{max=$1;}{r="";i=s=60*$1/max;while(i-->0)r=r"#";printf "%15s %5d %s %s",$2,$1,r,"\n";}'
```